# Flipping longitude and latitude coordinates in GeoPandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, latitude-longitude, shapely, geopandas

I'm working with datasets where latitudes and longitudes are sometimes mislabeled and I need to flip the longitudes and the latitudes. The best solution I could come up with is to extract the x an y coordinates using `df.geometry.x` and `df.geometry.y`, create a new geometry column, and reconstruct the GeoDataFrame using the new geometry column. Or in code form:

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

gdf['coordinates']  = list(zip(gdf.geometry.y, gdf.geometry.x))
gdf['coordinates'] = gdf['coordinates'].apply(Point)
gdf= gpd.GeoDataFrame(point_data, geometry='coordinates', crs = 4326)
```

This is pretty ugly, requires creating a new column and isn't efficient for large datasets. Is there an easier way to flip the longitude and latitude coordinates of a GeoSeries/ GeoDataFrame?

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way, I think what you have above the sensible solution.

Answer (score 1):

It works for Point and Polygon either:

```
gpd.GeoSeries(gdf['coordinates']).map(lambda polygon: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y: (y, x), polygon))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the geometry column directly:

```
df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda row: Point(row['y'], row['x']), axis=1)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=4326)
```